# React Datepicker disable specific hour on a date

Tags: reactjs, datepicker, react-datepicker

I am using https://reactdatepicker.com/. What I want to achieve is to exclude time on a specific date. I know we can exclude date and time but is there a way to combine both to only disable specific time on a date. For example disabling 18:30 for March 5th, 2021. I have a dynamic array of Dates

Thank you for all your help

Comment: try to use cron job https://www.npmjs.com/package/cron Cron is a tool that allows you to execute something on a schedule.

Comment: Thank you for your help, I will check that out but I guess that is for fixed dates. I have a dynamic array of dates and I want to disable the dates and times on that array, which will be dynamic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution where I used [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/docs/) for easy date formatting. You need to change the state of excluded times on select specific date. To pass hours to function setHours and minutes to function setMinutes you can use `moment().toObject();` https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/as-object/

```
import React from "react";
import moment from "moment";
import DatePicker from "react-datepicker";
import setHours from "date-fns/setHours";
import setMinutes from "date-fns/setMinutes";
import "react-datepicker/dist/react-datepicker.css";

const arrDates = [
  new Date(2021, 4, 20, 8, 15), //Thu May 20 2021 08:15:00
  new Date(2021, 4, 20, 8, 45), //Fri May 20 2021 08:45:00
  new Date(2021, 4, 21, 8, 30), //Sat May 21 2021 08:30:00
  new Date(2021, 4, 21, 9, 0) //Sat May 21 2021 09:00:00
];

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      selectedDate: setHours(setMinutes(new Date(2021, 4, 20, 8, 30), 0), 8),
      excludedTimes: []
    };
  }

  handleSelectedDate = (date) => {
    this.setState({
      selectedDate: date
    });
  };

  getExcludedTimes = (date) => {
    let arrSpecificDates = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < arrDates.length; i++) {
      if (
        moment(date, moment.ISO_8601).format("YYYY/MM/DD") ===
        moment(arrDates[i], moment.ISO_8601).format("YYYY/MM/DD")
      ) {
        arrSpecificDates.push(moment(arrDates[i], moment.ISO_8601).toObject());
      }
    }

    let arrExcludedTimes = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < arrSpecificDates.length; i++) {
      arrExcludedTimes.push(
       setHours(setMinutes(new Date(arrSpecificDates[i].minutes),arrSpecificDates[i].hours)
      );
      this.setState({
        excludedTimes: arrExcludedTimes
      });
    }
  };

  render() {
    const { selectedDate, excludedTimes } = this.state;
    return (
      <div className="container">
        <DatePicker
          selected={selectedDate}
          onChange={this.handleSelectedDate}
          onSelect={this.getExcludedTimes}
          popperPlacement="top-start"
          dateFormat="dd/MM/yyy"
          minDate={new Date()}
        />
        <DatePicker
          selected={selectedDate}
          excludeTimes={excludedTimes}
          onChange={this.handleSelectedDate}
          onSelect={this.getExcludedTimes}
          popperPlacement="top-start"
          showTimeSelect
          showTimeSelectOnly
          timeIntervals={15}
          timeFormat="HH:mm"
          dateFormat="hh:mm aa"
          minDate={new Date()}
          minTime={setHours(setMinutes(new Date(), 0), 8)}
          maxTime={setHours(setMinutes(new Date(), 45), 14)}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default App;
```

See full implementation: https://codesandbox.io/s/exclude-times-in-specific-dates-react-datepicker-o2ced?file=/src/App.js